# Convergence of the integral $\int \limits ^\infty _ 0 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(x+\cos(x))}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

My question is how to prove the convergence of integral 
$$\int \limits ^\infty _ 0 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(x+\cos(x))}$$
I already have, that $\int  \limits ^\infty _ 1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(x+\cos(x))}$ converges by using the substitution $y=\sqrt{x}$ and the majoring sum $\sum \limits ^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{1}{n^2-1}$, but I have no idea for the first part of the integral. Any suggestions?:)

Comment: Use that $x+\cos(x) \geq 1$ for $x\geq 0$ togeather with the fact that $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = 2$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

One may observe that, as $x \to 0^+$,
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{x}(x+\cos(x))}\sim \frac1{\sqrt{x}(x+1)} \sim \frac1{\sqrt{x}}
$$ and the latter integrand is integrable in a neighborhood of $0$, giving the **convergence** of
$$
\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(x+\cos(x))}.
$$